# Quadratic fields Factorization

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I've recently started learning number theory and was a bit confused by this problem. Let $K$ be a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$ denote primes and let $(q)=q_{1}^{e_{1}}\cdots q_{n}^{e^{n}}$ be the unique factorization of the principal ideal $(q)$ in the number field $O_{K}$. I am asked to show that

$$[O_{k}:qO_{k}]=q^{2}=\prod_{i=1}^{n}[O_{k}:q_{i}]^{e_{i}}.$$

$O_{K}$ has basis $1,\alpha$. I think I can prove the first equality by explicitly listing down the cosets. I am not sure how to do the next one. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: You might want to think about a "Chinese remainder theorem" type isomorphism between $\mathcal{O}_K/q\mathcal{O}_K$ and $\oplus \mathcal{O}_K/q_i^{e_i}$

Comment: Ok, got that. Now, it reduces to showing that $[O_{K},q_{i}^{e_{i}}]=[O_{K},q_{i}]^{e_{i}}$.